# dataProvider does not refresh when adding new item

Tags: java, vaadin, dataprovider

I am using a DataProvider to keep my grid up to date. `.refreshItem(item)` works perfectly fine for modifying existing items. My issue starts when I need to introduce new items in my grid. To do so I use a form that when save is pressed calls `dataProvider.refreshAll()` unfortunately this seems to do nothing I need to refresh the page manually in order to see the new item.

My `dataProvider` gets its data from a DB as follows:

```
var technologyList = technologyService.findAllTechnologies();

dataProvider = DataProvider.ofCollection(technologyList);
```

Comment: Where is your collection comming from? Is it database backend, or...

Comment: @AndréSchild a database

Comment: @spozzi Are you sure the data is stored in the database?

Comment: @gidravlic Now that you say it like that no. I am new to this and I am trying to learn. I made an edit to show how i created my dataProvider

Comment: @gidravlic thank you! thank you! thank you! I managed to fix it so that the grid takes it's values from the DB instead of a dataProvider. Thanks for the little help!